# SetEnvironmentVariable() does not seem to set values that can be retrieved by getenv()

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, environment-variables

I have an EXE which, at startup, sets an **environment variable** (ie: `MAGICK_CODER_MODULE_PATH=xxx`) via the Windows API `SetEnvironmentVariable()`.

When I look in Process Explorer (from SysInternals) at the list of environment variables set to my EXE I can see the environment variable I just set before (`MAGICK_CODER_MODULE_PATH`), so everything looks good at this point.

Then I instruct my EXE to load a DLL via `LoadLibrary()`. The problem arises a little later when this DLL tries to get the value of my environment variable via `getenv("MAGICK_CODER_MODULE_PATH")`: **it returns NULL**! How could this be possible? It looks like `getenv()` ignores the value I just set before with `SetEnvironmentVariable()`.

**Note:**

- This seems to not happen when the DLL is compiled with an old version of Visual Studio (maybe related to `vcruntime140.dll` / `msvcp140.dll`).
- If I open a command prompt, do `@SET MAGICK_CODER_MODULE_PATH=xxx`, and from this command prompt then launch my EXE, then everything works fine: the DLL successfully gets the value of `MAGICK_CODER_MODULE_PATH` via `getenv()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing APIs: Windows' `SetEnvironmentVariable` bypasses the C++ runtime, so that the copy of the environment that is stored in your program is not updated. The later `getenv` call looks into this copy and doesn't find your change.

Use the same API level for both calls. Either [`getenv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getenv-wgetenv) and [`_putenv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/putenv-wputenv), or use the Windows API [`GetEnvironmentVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getenvironmentvariable) and [`SetEnvironmentVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setenvironmentvariable).

Comment: With a caveat of `putenv` not being thread-safe. I believe, consensus is to use Windows API.

Comment: thanks, but I can't update the dll (it's a tiers code), I can only update my delphi exe, but in it I have only SetEnvironmentVariable function exposed. Do you know how I can access from my exe (not made in C) the function _putenv?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. If the Delphi EXE updates its own process environment *before* loading a C++ DLL, then the DLL should see the new environment when it creates a local copy for `getenv()`/`_putenv()` to then read/write. So, this issue only makes sense if the EXE is updating the environment *after* loading the DLL.

Comment: In any case, check if your Delphi EXE process is getting the `msvcrt##.dll` or `ucrtbase.dll` runtime DLL loaded into it by the C++ DLL in question. If so, then the EXE can find the runtime DLL's `HMODULE` handle via `GetModuleHandle()`, and then retrieve a pointer to `_putenv/_s()` via `GetProcAddress()`, and then call it.

Comment: [This post from Christmas 2005 in a SourceForge thread](https://sourceforge.net/p/firebird/mailman/message/17540267/) explains why and how both worlds differ.