# How to call _putenv from Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Is there a (simple) way to call [`_putenv()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/putenv-wputenv?view=msvc-160) from my Delphi app?

This is a follow-up of [SetEnvironmentVariable() does not seem to set values that can be retrieved by getenv()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69199708/4299358).

Comment: These functions seem to be a part of the Microsoft C Runtime Library -- not a part of Windows.

Comment: And you're sure you don't want [`SetEnvironmentVariable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setenvironmentvariable)?

Comment: @AmigoJack yes sure i need _putenv, because of this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69199708/setenvironmentvariable-does-not-seem-to-set-values-that-can-be-retrieved-by-gete/

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand yes look like a microsoft C runtime, but how can I properly call it from delphi ?

Comment: @zeus Delphi is not C. The C runtime will not exist in your Delphi app, unless you are linking to an external library that uses the C runtime. Why do you think you need to call C functions in Delphi code? What is the real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Assuming you do actually need to do what you say, then Ylyou need to link to whichever runtime in your process is calling _getenv, and import and call _putenv. But it seems plausible that you have misdiagnosed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69199708/), you Delphi EXE is loading a DLL written in C++. So, check if your EXE process is getting the `msvcrt##.dll` or `ucrtbase.dll` runtime DLL loaded into it by the C++ DLL in question. If so, then the EXE can find the runtime DLL's `HMODULE` handle via `GetModuleHandle()`, and then retrieve a pointer to `_putenv/_s()` via `GetProcAddress()`, and then call it.

Comment: you are the best it's exactly this, a blank delphi app is loading at starting the msvcrt.dll (don't know why but it's like this) with take a cache of the environment variables, so when later I call setEnvironementVariable and later load a dll with use also msvcrt.dll and try to call getenv from this dll, then it's use the cache of msvcrt.dll and don't see the change I made just before  via setEnvironementVariable, that a shame :( I I will try now to import from msvcrt.dll the _putenv and use it instead of setEnvironementVariable. don't understand why such ugly getenv exist :(

Comment: I did this before for `_errno: function: PInteger; cdecl;` for similar reasons: it worked just like any other import and I was then able to check for failures of previous calls in those DLLs.